# Find a word for 3rd person interference in telephone call

Tags: single-word-requests

Let suppose following situation:

There is a company private/internal telephone network. The network has got a special feature, that a private telephone call between two office workers can be monitored by a supervisor/manager. That said supervisor can also *interfere* into the call in a way that he can say something into a microphone that will be heard by both office workers.

What would be the best matching word choice for the given situation?

Example sentence:

> <...> into private call took place on Monday at 01:15 PM o'clock.

(The preposition 'into' could be of course replaced or removed depending on proper grammar collocation)

Already found: *interference* or *intrusion* does not sound good because of subjective opinion. (Has got a pejorative expression)

**Edit**

To clarify, we can suppose that so called manager is already listening the call (this process is already named as *monitoring*). I'm going to find a word describing an event when he starts to say something.

I also prefer words from formal language (not any slang).

Comment: *intervention?*

Comment: Maybe just ***break** [into the call]*

Comment: You're sentence makes it seem like you're reporting an incident.  How is this not pejorative?  But how about "The three-way conference calling feature was exercised..."

Comment: The supervisor can override the private call feature and like FumbleFingers said break into the call.

Comment: Supervisor *dropped in*...

Comment: with OP's latest edit of the question  ... i shall bow out.

Comment: Stoneyb should make *intervention* an answer as it's the best fit. The OPs situation is analogous to a driving instructor who is monitoring his student, only making an *intervention* in a dangerous situation.

Comment: I think you'll find there's nothing special about that because it's telephone call. What would you call the same process if two people were talking - however formally - and a third who'd been merely listening/monitoring/eavesdropping/spying then spoke up/out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time (back before things like call waiting and caller ID), this was a standard feature for telephone communication: in an emergency, the operator could *interrupt* an ongoing telephone conversation. Per Wikipedia, this was called [***busy-line interrupt***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_line_interrupt) or ***emergency breakthrough*** (though I vaguely remember it as "operator interruption"). The words *interrupt* and *interruption* are sufficiently common that I think you could use either and be understood.

If you specifically want a noun, *interruption* is the obvious choice, but I think the computer/electronic use of *interrupt* as a noun (as in the landline expression) would make that a plausible choice, as well. In either case I might use "monitor" or "supervisor" as a modifier. So in your example:

> **Supervisor interrupt[ion]** into private call took place on Monday at 01:15 PM.

If you specified a *call* interrupt(ion), you could omit the "private call" part:

> **Supervisor call interrupt[ion]** took place on Monday at 01:15 PM.

Answer (score -1):

M-W gives the following definitions without caveats:

> [Definition of
>   **kibitz**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kibitz)
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1: to act as a kibitzer
>
> 2: to exchange comments: chat
>
> transitive verb: to observe as a kibitzer; especially: *kibitz a card game*

and

> [Definition of
>   **kibitzer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kibitzer):
>
> one who looks on and often offers unwanted advice or comment: *a
>   kibitzer at a card game*;
>
> broadly: one who offers opinions
>
> First Known Use: 1922

Answer (score -1):

**Interloping** into a private call took place on Monday at 01:15 PM o'clock.

> Definition [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interloping) of interlope; interloped; interloping.
>   intransitive verb 1 : to encroach on the rights (as in trade) of
>   others 2 : intrude, interfere

Synonyms of interlope: [same dictionary - thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/interloping)

> **butt in**, interfere, intermeddle, intrude, meddle, mess, muck (about or
>   around), nose, obtrude, poke, pry, snoop

Comment: Where is this definition from? You need to cite your source.

Comment: OK, I see you've attributed some parts of the answer (good), but you still need to add a source for the definition you're using (which doesn't come from that link).

Comment: Snooping is listening in, eavesdropping.  I think OP wants to describe breaking in and saying something as well as listening.

Comment: @Jim single word request for 2 actions is a  tall order. I guess i am stuck.  Should I rescind my answer?